# find specific pattern in string and remove it

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I want to remove xxxx-xxxx in string.

1. String data = "help text 2015-2016 dummy string";

   **Need output:  help text dummy string**
2. String data = "abcd 2057-3827 any string";

**Need output: abcd any string**

Comment: Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow -- we expect 
questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems -- but we 
will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us 
[what you've tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com), and where you are stuck. 
This will also help us answer your question better.

Answer (score 1):

The following code should work:

```
String regexp = "[^\\s]{4}-[^\\s]{4}\\s";
String str = "help text 2015-2016 dummy string";
System.out.println(str.replaceFirst(regexp, ""));
```

If `xxxx-xxxx` is always a number, then you can use:

```
String r = "[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{4}\\s";
```

Comment: Thanks, it's working fine.